# How to make an object follow a Rigid Body as if the object is parented to it in animation

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I am making an animation of a box opening. I have a lock which I want to unlock and throw in the air, that is animated. So I added the *Rigid Body* physics to the lock to make it fall realistically to the ground.

However, that lock is made of 2 separate objects, so they can be animated separately. Then after that, I would like to have them fall down as if they were joined - one rigid object. However, I can't have both so I need a way around it. I've tried parenting, but it's not possible. It seems some of the object constraints would work best, but can't find the right one.
[image]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are both objects animated or only one?

Comment: Check my solution, should work, as I've tested it on a lock myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In case one object is animated:**

Select your animated object, and go to object constraints>Child Of>Select your other object. Now when your animation is finished, or at the frame you want the rigid body to start, go to scene properties>rigid body world>cache>set that as the start frame. Now your inanimated object will drop and the other one will follow it.

**In case both objects are animated:**

Go to the child of constraint, set it to zero, and press 'I' on the influence value to keyframe it. Now go to one frame before the frame in which you want your lock to start dropping (which of course is the frame In which your keyframe animation is finished), and press I to keyframe again. On the very next frame, set the influence to 1 and press 'I' to keyframe. When your animation is finished, or at the frame you want the rigid body to start, go to scene properties>rigid body world>cache>set that as the start frame. Now make sure the other object has a rigid body, and you're good to go.

Comment: It works, but problem is, it's very dizzy, it's rotating and shaking. Is it about rigid body settings or

Comment: @Radoon It must be fixed by tweaking a few settings, I could test and try if it gets better if you can share your .blend file.

Comment: I added blend file with just lock. Hope it's okay, because it's project work and didn't want to make whole scene available

Comment: Yes, that's fine @Radoon. Will update in a few minutes.